# Write more than one element with same name to xml file using JDOM in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jdom

I have to loop through an object containing the data for all the xml elements, set the values accordingly and write it into a file.

Here is my source code,

```
for(int i=0;i< dataHolder.getNumSensorsList().size();i++) {

    NumSensor numSensor = (NumSensor) dataHolder.getNumSensorsList().get(i);
    Element numSensorElement = new Element("numSensor");
    numSensorElement.setAttribute("ruleid",numSensor.getRuleId());

    Element type = new Element("type");
    type.addContent(numSensor.getUnit());
    numSensorElement.addContent(type);

    Element sensorId = new Element("sensorId");
    sensorId.addContent(numSensor.getSensorId());
    numSensorElement.addContent(sensorId);

    Element label = new Element("label");
    label.addContent(numSensor.getLabel());
    numSensorElement.addContent(label);
}
```

In case if am looping for three times and adding different data to "`numSensorElement`" all three times and I add the "`numSensorElement`" to a root tag and write it into a xml file. I am getting three copies of "`numSensorElement`" with the information from third loop. First two loops are replaced and written with third loop values for three times.

Please help me with some better approach than mine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you print these in the loop?
numSensor.getRuleId(), numSensor.getUnit() and numSensor.getLabel()

And then share the complete output you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry that I have my list wrongly manipulated. The problem was with the list I had, not with the element. Thanks for the suggestion.